# Parsing string into key value pairs C#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have method where I call another API. From

`var activeCustomers = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`
I get string which contains `[timestamp, value]` objects:

`{"values":[[1298937600000,1],[1459468800000,16],[1462060800000,527],[1464739200000,173],[1467331200000,132],[1470009600000,166],[1472688000000,151],[1475280000000,172],[1477958400000,139],[1480550400000,129],[1483228800000,116],[1485907200000,133],[1488326400000,180],[1491004800000,227],[1493596800000,281],[1496275200000,263],[1498867200000,230],[1501545600000,326],[1504224000000,403],[1506816000000,442],[1509494400000,1019],[1512086400000,650],[1514764800000,708],[1564617600000,2614],[1567296000000,2527],[1569888000000,3144],[1572566400000,3075],[1575158400000,2541],[1577836800000,2246],[1580515200000,2456],[1583020800000,885]]}`

I want to parse these values into key value pairs, but I am not sure what's the most optimal way for that.

I tried removing beginning and ending of string and cast it as object but it stays as one big string inside the ienumerable:

```
            int index = activeCustomers.IndexOf(":");
            if (index > 0)
                activeCustomers = activeCustomers.Substring(index + 1);
            activeCustomers = activeCustomers.Remove(activeCustomers.Length - 1);

            var results = ((IEnumerable) activeCustomers).Cast<object>();
```

I also tried making regex for that but I am not very comfortable with that.

Comment: it's JSON. just use a JSON-deserialiser.

Comment: Why not just deserialize the JSON.  Your string consists of an object with a single property "values" that is an array of arrays.  The inner array always consists of a pair of numbers (the first a long, the second an int).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov it seems, that linked duplicate isn't correct. OP can use JSON deserialization

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski thanks - not sure why I end up with that wrong duplicate. Updated to correct on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just a JSON with array of arrays, which can be easily deserialized using Json.NET

```cs
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(activeCustomers);
```

or `System.Text.Json`

```cs
var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(activeCustomers);
```

Where `Root` is

```cs
public class Root
{
    public long[][] values { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can map the `values` property to any desired structure using [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netcore-3.1) method

```cs
var pairs = result.values.Select(v => new { timestamp = v[0], value = v[1] }).ToList();
```